# is it ok to copy and paste an adBanner i have on one screen to the next without changing code?

Tags: ios, iad, adbannerview

i have an adbanner on my first screen and i was wondering if its ok to simply copy and paste it onto all my other screens or would it also require coding ?

P.s would having the adbanner on more than one screen make more revenue or one screen is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the ad banner on multiple screens would probably slightly increase the likelihood of a user noticing the ad and clicking through (which generates the revenue for you). It would make sense to code against the API to get the ad and display it on each screen as the API will handle tracking the click throughs and refreshing with a new ad after a specified amount of time.

Comment: ok i got the first part, what do you mean code against the API ? elaborate please @brandoncampbell and can you educate me further on the sort of code i should use...